# How to connect with xamarin form between a webapi en an android device?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, maui

When I start in visual studio 2022 an webapi and a xamerinform(.NET MAUI) I cannot create a connection between de fysical andriod device with de .NET MAUI app and the webapi on my local machine.
Do I need to open some ports(redirect?)
I can't get further with testing my application now on Android.

When working on .NET MAUI on my windows machine, it's ok, but debug on a physical android device, I expected that there would be some kind of tunnel so testing would be easy. Can't find a way out.

Comment: Usually it should be enough for your device to be connected to the same network. In the settings however you have to switch from localhost to the actual IP address.

Comment: Will my laptop alow a (Lan) request to the webapi in that case? No securtiy issues with that?

Comment: I suppose your local web api is http, then you need to add to MainApplication.cs the UsesCleartextTraffic = true value. You dont need to open any ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This scenario is always a bit complicated for newcomers. Here is the gist. Where I say .NET MAUI, you can also replace it with Xamarin.Forms, or even any client technology basically.

### The Problem

If you run your .NET MAUI Windows app on the same machine as your backend, you can simply connect to `localhost` and that will work just fine. Now, when you run your app on Android (or iOS) if you try to connect to `localhost`, then it tries to find your backend on the Android or iOS device. Doesn't matter if that is an emulator or a physical device. Even though an emulator runs on the same machine, it acts like a separate device.

### Hard Solution

So the first thing you want to do is figure out the IP address that you backend server is on and connect to that. Then depending on your OS and a lot of other things, you might need to open a port etc.

But then, there is the issue of a secure connection. Luckily, but a bit annoying, Android and iOS now force us to use secure connections. And typically your backend development service doesn't have it's own SSL cert. Now you suddenly need to add all kinds of disabling of security features in your app to still be able to connect from iOS/Android to your development backend service.

All of this is described in great detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/local-web-services).

### Easy Solution: Dev Tunnels

With Dev Tunnels this becomes much easier! Dev Tunnels allows you to run a little CLI tool on your machine that can open up your local development machine to the world (including your iOS/Android device) *and* provides a secure connection.

A reference for the Dev Tunnels CLI can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/dev-tunnels/cli-commands).

#### Dev Tunnels Quick Start

1. Install the CLI tool

On Windows run: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/TunnelsCliDownload/win-x64 -OutFile devtunnel.exe .\devtunnel.exe -h`

On macOS/Linux run: `curl -sL https://aka.ms/DevTunnelCliInstall | bash`

2. Run `devtunnel user login` to login with your Azure account
3. Host a tunnel with `devtunnel host -p 8080` where `8080` is the port that your development service is running on. You will presented with a (secure) URL that you can use to connect to.

You might want to add the `-a` switch which allows for anonymous connections. Else for each connection you need to login with your Azure account. Regardless of using the `-a` switch, the first time you go to the URL there will be a webpage that you need to acknowledge, so make sure you go there first and click the button and then connect from your app.

Additionally, make sure that your development server is accepting connections from outside (usually make it listen to `0.0.0.0` for ASP.NET projects) and let it run on http (so not https) so that a certificate that might be in place is not conflicting with the one from Dev Tunnels and causing disconnects.

I have a video walking you through all of this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azuC8SFHWp8).

### Alternatives

There has been an alternative for all this for a long time already called [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Functionality is basically the same but works a bit different.